# Proguard error: there were 211 duplicate class definitions

Tags: android, proguard, scoreloop

I am having the following error while exporting after integrating Scoreloop. Before that it was fine.

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Note: there were 211 duplicate class definitions.
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitEnclosingMethodAttribute(ClassObfuscator.java:182)
.........
.............
```

and probably more 210 number of errors which I didn't give here. I mentioned Scoreloop in proguard-project.txt the following way:

```
#############
# Scoreloop #
#############
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.**
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.fortumo.FortumoPaymentProviderController {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.fortumo.FortumoPaymentProvider {*;}
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.paypalx.PayPalXPaymentProviderController {*;}
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.WebViewDialog
-keep class com.scoreloop.client.android.core.ui.WebViewDialog {*;}
-keep class com.facebook.android.** {*;}
```

How to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by myself. Just thought why don't I call all the scoreloop classes together and see what happens; and it worked. After the line:

```
-dontwarn com.scoreloop.client.android.core.paymentprovider.**
```

I've added:

```
-keep class com.scoreloop.** {*;}
```

And that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

If you succeeded to sign before, it's the same situation that I experienced.

After deleting the proguard folder in the project, I try to sign the apk again.

It succeeded!

Comment: most important thing! first, you should backup the proguard forder.

Comment: Where can I find the proguard folder? I cant find a proguard folder on my project directory.

Comment: Where is the proguard folder you mention ?

Answer (score 0):

use `-dontnote` instead of `dontwarn`.

Ref: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage